# JQuery / on() and not exists element in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code:

```
$(".tabs__nav[data-tab-id='2'").on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).off();
    var projects = [];
    $('.project').each(function () {
        var detail = new _detailMozaik2.default($(this));
        detail.init();
        projects.push(detail);
    });
});
```

'.project' items are main problem, cause these items appear after clicking on tab - Nette snippet (ajax) - items not exist before jQuery inits the on() function.

How to edit code, or what jQuery function have to use?
Thanks

Comment: There is typo in `$(".tabs__nav[data-tab-id='2'")`. You are not closing the `]`

Comment: Read about [__`Event delegation`__](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Were any syntax errors thrown? You have a syntax error in your code here on line 1

Comment: Sorry for syntax error but it's not the problem...

Comment: Event delegation not the problem... problem is element '.project' (not a .tab__nav or .tab__nav's child).

Comment: It's very unclear what your problem is. Is it that the items from diferent tabs keep adding to your projects[] array?

Comment: Can you show us the code that creates the `.project` elements?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that .projects from other tabs still apear because they have the .project class anyway.

Start your JQuery with your target tab

```html
$(e.target).find('.project').each(function () {
  var detail = new _detailMozaik2.default($(this));
  detail.init();
  projects.push(detail);
});
```

Comment: Thats not working.
.on() function inits (and callbeck as well) before the .project items (these items wont the event handlers) exists in DOM... How to init .on() callback function after 'click' event will?